# Show login Page when user is not Authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to authorized the request in my project and I have an issue with popuppage.On button click I have open bootstrap dialog using below code.

```
$('#divModalActionPage .modal-body').load(strUrl, function(e){
                var html=$("#divModalActionPage .modal-body").html();
                var IsvalidJSON=IsJsonString(html);

                        $('#divModalActionPage').modal({
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            //keyboard: false,
                            show: true
                        })
            }
```

And strUrl action decorate with [CustomAuthorize] attribute and my CustomAuthorize contains following code.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                filterContext.Result=new ContentResult() { Content = "<script>top.window.location.href='/Home/Index'</script>" };

            }

        }
```

The issue is that when I click on the button it will go to check use is authenticated or not but not redirect me to the login page.